# Input field placeholder does not disappear if text is inserted from browser's history

Tags: bug

I was editing a question and noticed the following behavior:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

If text is inserted from Firefox's history list, the placeholder/hint will not be removed and as a result one is on top of the other. I suspect the JS code involved only clears the field when a key is hit and when the right mouse button is clicked, so this insertion is not detected.

The browser is Firefox 41.0.1 on Windows 8.1.

I can't say if the same happens in other browsers since I only have made edits using Firefox, so it's the only browser where I have something in the history list.

Comment: I'm not sure why a pseudo-placeholder (`<span class="edit-field-overlay">briefly explain your changes (corrected spelling, fixed grammar, improved formatting)</span>`) is used, possibly it's a relic from back when placeholders weren't widely supported yet.

Comment: Up voting because I was able to reproduce this in Firefox on Windows 7 professional.

Comment: Most likely related to the site JS watching input events. I ran into that issue with FF before too, where it wasn't triggering change events for autofilled inputs...